# get rid of warning: Inbound TCP/IP connection failed

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get this warning intermittently:

> Inbound TCP/IP connection failed:
> connection from sender terminated
> before handshake header received. 0
> bytes were received. Please check
> sender for additional details.

I see this sometimes when a subscriber unsubscribes a topic. I am assuming the warning is issued if the unsubscription happens while the next message is already coming in.
The concrete place I am seeing this is when using smach monitor_state. When a monitored topic delivers a message that satisfies the state, it unsubscribes, and sometimes, I see the above warning.

I want to get rid of warnings, when they really don't indicate a problem.

Can I unsubscribe in a way that is more "clean" and doesn't cause this warning?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286309/get-rid-of-warning:-inbound-tcp/ip-connection-failed/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-05-30**:
Did you find the source of this warning showing up>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe you have solve it. remove rospy.spin() after your callback and change to

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    continue
```

---

Originally posted by [skyap](https://answers.ros.org/users/35753/skyap/) with karma: 26 on 2018-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-05-30**:
is there a reason for which this helps? I also have the same warning sometimes showing up in my ros application although it doesn't seem to effect the behaviour of it. But I don't know what the source of it can be. however, I have a node that I keep alive with a while loop but not using rospy.is_shutdown().